# Accessing Child model via DetailView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i have two models Farmer and Animals. Animal(s) are related to Farmer(s) via ForeignKey.

As you see below in the Template, i want to display a farmer and with his related animals. My Template displays the first_name, last_name and city, correctly the only missing are the related animals from the child model.

In other projects i used "{% for item in ParentModel.ChildModel_set.all %}" to access the child model unfortunately it does not work this time.

Is that because i used a DetailView?

**models.py**

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    objects = FarmerManager() # --- link to Manager

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("datainput:farmer_detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    farmer = models.ForeignKey('Farmer', related_name='farmername', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = AnimalManager() # --- link to Manager

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("datainput:animal_detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

**views.py**

```
class FarmerDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name ="datainput/farmer_detail.html"
    queryset = Farmer.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        some_id = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Farmer, id=some_id)
```

**urls.py**

```
<...>
    path('farmer/<int:id>/', FarmerDetailView.as_view(), name='farmer_detail'),
<...>
```

**farmer_detail.html**

```
<...>    
<div class="row" id="p1">
        <div class="col-6 offset-md-3">
            <p> Bauer {{ farmer.first_name }}  {{ farmer.last_name }}</p>  in {{ farmer.city }} 
            {% for animals in farmer.animal_set.all %}
            <p>  {{ animals }} </p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>
<...>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that because i used a `DetailView`?

**No**, it is because you used `related_name` the wrong way.

The [**`related_name`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) is the name of the relationship in *reverse*:

> The name to use for the relation from the **related object back to this one**. It’s also the default value for `related_query_name` (the name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model).

That means that if an `Animal` has a foreign key to `Farmer`, the `related_name` should contain the name of the relation from the `Farmer` to its `Animal`s. `farmername` is *not* a good idea here.

You can rename this as:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    # ...
    farmer = models.ForeignKey('Farmer', related_name='animals', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

In your template, you can then iterate over the `.animals`:

```
{% for animals in farmer.animals.all %}
<p>  {{ animals }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can *omit* specifying the `related_name`. Django then automatically uses `modelname_set`, so here that is the `animal_set`:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    # ...
    farmer = models.ForeignKey('Farmer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

and then use `animal_set`, like you did before:

```
{% for animals in farmer.animal_set.all %}
<p>  {{ animals }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: alright i will check my whole project. where i used "farmername"  as "related_name" and change it. So far it work with "farmername.all".  I guess i will put a big mark on my django notes, so i don´t miss it next time. thanks